# Multiple line 3D plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have 3 dataframes:

```
> head(ps_data)
      mass        value
1 1197.106 0.0003046761
2 1197.312 0.0002792939
3 1197.518 0.0002545125
4 1197.724 0.0002304614
5 1197.930 0.0002072700
6 1198.136 0.0001850678

> head(enf_data)
      mass        value
1 1252.358 0.0001400532
2 1252.560 0.0001380179
3 1252.761 0.0001360147
4 1252.963 0.0001336038
5 1253.165 0.0001310146
6 1253.367 0.0001278587
> head(uti_data)

      mass        value
1 1209.999 9.404051e-05
2 1210.204 9.176861e-05
3 1210.409 8.892953e-05
4 1210.614 8.613961e-05
5 1210.819 8.299913e-05
6 1211.024 8.038693e-05
```

I need to plot something close to this:
[image]

Where z axis will be the "value" column, y axis will be the "mass" column and the x axis will be each dataframe.

I tried to plot this using plotly package, but I'm not getting it right.
How can I do it?

EDIT: dput as requested.

```
structure(list(mass = c(1197.10568602095, 1197.31161534199, 1197.51756246145, 
1197.72352737934, 1197.92951009569, 1198.1355106105), value = c(0.000304676093184434, 
0.000279293920415841, 0.000254512541389108, 0.000230461422005283, 
0.000207270028165387, 0.000185067825770437), group = c("PS", 
"PS", "PS", "PS", "PS", "PS")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(mass = c(1252.3578527531, 1252.55956147119, 1252.76128739414, 
1252.96303052216, 1253.16479085545, 1253.3665683942), value = c(0.000140053215421452, 
0.000138017894050617, 0.00013601474884925, 0.000133603848925069, 
0.000131014621271734, 0.000127858739055662), group = c("ENF", 
"ENF", "ENF", "ENF", "ENF", "ENF")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(mass = c(1209.99938731277, 1210.20436650703, 1210.40936335465, 
1210.61437785568, 1210.81941001019, 1211.02445981824), value = c(9.40405108642129e-05, 
9.17686135352109e-05, 8.89295335433793e-05, 8.61396097238083e-05, 
8.29991287322805e-05, 8.03869281229029e-05), group = c("UTI", 
"UTI", "UTI", "UTI", "UTI", "UTI")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT 2:

Got some progress using plotly:

```
ps_data["group"] <- "PS"
enf_data["group"] <- "ENF"
uti_data["group"] <- "UTI"
all_data <- rbind(ps_data,enf_data,uti_data)
all_long <- melt(all_data, id.vars=c("mass","group","value"))

fig <- plot_ly(all_long, x = ~group, y = ~mass, z = ~value, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
        opacity = 1, line = list(width = 6, color = ~group, reverscale = FALSE))

fig
```

[image]

But some strange lines appeared in x axis and the colors are not right.

EDIT 3:

I managed to plot something quite good.

My data looks like this:

```
> head(all_data)
      mass        value group
1 1197.106 0.0003046761    PS
2 1197.312 0.0002792939    PS
3 1197.518 0.0002545125    PS
4 1197.724 0.0002304614    PS
5 1197.930 0.0002072700    PS
6 1198.136 0.0001850678    PS
```

The dataframe is huge, with three groups (PS, ENF, UTI).

I can't fit all of it here, but I decided to place the head just for you to see the structure.

With this data I used this:

```
p3 <- plot_ly(all_data, x = ~group, y = ~mass, z = ~value, split = ~group, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
              line = list(width = 4))
```

Now I'm just trying to find some reliable way to save it in TIFF and change the axis titles.

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput` to create the sampledata, such that we can simply copy and paste it.

Comment: I've never used it, I added something there, is that enough/helpful?

Comment: Yes, thats fine. Thank you

Comment: really you have 3 separate traces,  not one.  that's why you are getting diagonal line in single trace

Comment: @RobRaymond, so I need to plot using 3 separated trances? I tried using add_trace(), but got some strange errors.